# How Expression.Evaluate works?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, evaluation, m

How to parameterize The first day of Month in **Power Query**?

Tried this way (`Expression.Evaluate` + `Day.Monday`), but gives the error:

```
let
    txtFirstDayOfMonth = "Monday", // this parameter comes from Excel/Source file
    numFirstDayOfMonth = Expression.Evaluate("Day."&txtFirstDayOfMonth)        
in
    numFirstDayOfMonth
```

Estimated output:

```
numFirstDayOfMonth =  1   // numFirstDayOfMonth = Day.Monday
```

Real output:

```
    Expression.Error: [1,1-1,11] The name 'Day.Monday' doesn't exist in the current context.
        Details:
        [List]
```

P.S. Want to avoid hack with `switch` statement.

**THE ANSWER (Summary)**:

```
Expression.Evaluate("Day."&txtFirstDayOfMonth,#shared)
```

[please see details in this post by Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70248352/6165594)

However, as *Jeroen Mostert* mentions in comments, probably it's better to use `switch` or `else if` construction for this purpose(as far as there is no `switch` statement in power query). Something like:

```
...
#"Added Conditional numFirstDayOfWeek" = Table.AddColumn
(#"Added Custom", "numFirstDayOfWeek", each 
     if Text.Contains(Text.Lower([FirstDayOfWeek]), "su") then 0 
else if Text.Contains(Text.Lower([FirstDayOfWeek]), "mo") then 1 
else if Text.Contains(Text.Lower([FirstDayOfWeek]), "tu") then 2 
else if Text.Contains(Text.Lower([FirstDayOfWeek]), "we") then 3 
else if Text.Contains(Text.Lower([FirstDayOfWeek]), "th") then 4 
else if Text.Contains(Text.Lower([FirstDayOfWeek]), "fr") then 5 
else if Text.Contains(Text.Lower([FirstDayOfWeek]), "sa") then 6 
else 1
)
```

Comment: Evaluating arbitrary text coming from Excel sound like a terrible idea. A `switch` (or a table lookup) sounds like exactly what is needed, rather than a "hack" -- dynamic evaluation would be the hack. :P Because you need to supply the environment for `Evaluate` (precisely to prevent shenanigans), you'd need to actually list and bind the identifiers (`Day.Monday = Day.Monday`, `Day.Tuesday = Day.Tuesday`, etcetera), which would leave you considerably worse off in terms of keystrokes.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert for your feedback. Updated the post according your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nomenclature with regard to first day of month is confusing me, but to return your expected value from `Expression.Evaluate` you need to define the environment.  As written, `Expression.Evaluate` does not understand `Day.`. So we add a record of the global enviroment using `#shared` keyword (which includes the record fields cited by @JeroenMostert, but seems simpler to add to the function).

```
Expression.Evaluate("Day."&txtFirstDayOfMonth,#shared)
```

will return the weekday number of `txtFirstDayOfMonth` where that is a weekday name.

There are a number of blogs going into more detail about the environment variable.  See [this](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/02/06/expression-evaluate-in-power-querym/) by Chris Webb for more enlightenment.

If I were doing this, however, I'd probably just make a `List` of the weekdays and use the `List.PositionOf` function to return the number. And also add some code to avoid issues with typos, capitalization, etc -- maybe just look at the first three letter.

Comment: `#shared` certainly solves that particular problem, at the expense of now allowing an Excel user to call *any* M function that happens to be in scope, which is the kind of great power that is never used with great responsibility. Although the damage you can do with M is limited in theory since functions are not supposed to modify things (what with M being a functional language), in practice a function can do anything it pleases, including call out to external sources and execute arbitrary SQL. Personally I'd prefer a solution that can't escape the bounds I set for it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Nice analysis. As I intimated (and you also pointed out in your comment), I prefer a different solution that does not make use of `Expression.Evaluate` at all.

Comment: Ron - do you always avoid Expression.Evaluate or just in this particular case? Are there any drawbacks to using it? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to go for the Expression.Evaluate way (I'm not sure I would) here's some thoughts.

Youcan specify your identifiers in two ways. Either you do it manually with a record:

```
[Day.Monday = Day.Monday, Day.Tuesday = Day.Tuesday ]
```

Or you can make use of the #shared global identifier.

For example:

```
Expression.Evaluate(
  "List.Sum( { 1, 2, 3 } )", 
  [List.Sum = List.Sum] 
)
```

Returns the same as:

```
Expression.Evaluate(
  "List.Sum( { 1, 2, 3 } )", 
  #shared 
)
```

More examples on this you can find here:
https://powerquery.how/expression-evaluate/

Comment: Any reason you'd avoid using Expression.Evaluate? I'm about to use it in Prod and performance doesn't seem like an issue. Cheers